# Создание экземпляра класса

Tags: c#, ооп, классы

Здравствуйте, форумчане.
Требуется Ваша помощь, если кто-то найдет минутку, буду очень благодарен.
Ситуация следующая- мной в консольном проекте среде VisualStudio13 был разработан класс ServerConnector, который содержит методы для обмена информацией с сервером.
в этом же консольном проекте код

```
        ServerConnector MyConector;
        dtTempTable = new DataTable();
        MyConector = new ServerConnector("192.168.0.103", 2200);
        dtTempTable = MyConector.exequteSQLRequest("INSERT INTO Reestr(Id,Name,SurName,BirdthData,City,Phone,parol,rparol) values ('2','Romah','Baj','25','Borik','093','123','123')");
        Console.WriteLine("Request Exequted");
```

выполнялся без проблем

клиент должен иметь графическую оболочку, я создал для этого проект WIndowsForms, в который я поместил этот класс. Проблема заключается в том, что не могу создать в глобальной области имен проекта экземпляр этого класса, так как к нему будет обращаться обработчики событий нескольких форм.

методом тыка я разобрался, что можна определить  класс как статический и все методы придется определить как статические, но что-то мне подсказывает что это неправильный путь решения задачи.
наверняка есть какие-то особенности проектов WindowsFormsкоторых я незнаю, помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Comment: Вы не должны передавать параметры через глобальные переменные. Забудьте о статическом классе. Пусть бизнес-логика приложения создаст экземпляр модельного класса, работающего с данными, и передаст его (или сами данные, тут уж вам решать) коду формы.

Comment: как создать экземпляр модельного класса? я просто не понимаю чем модельный класс отличается от обычного. может посоветуете какие-то статьи или примеры.

Comment: может вам подойдет шаблон singleton http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%E4%E8%ED%EE%F7%EA%E0_(%F8%E0%E1%EB%EE%ED_%EF%F0%EE%E5%EA%F2%E8%F0%EE%E2%E0%ED%E8%FF)#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.80_.D0.BD.D0.B0_C.23
с точки зрения архитектуры - кошмар, но вашу задачу может решить

Comment: @pj-infest: модельный класс — это обычный класс. Но ваш код должен быть структурирован, поделён на части. Если у вас есть UI и база данных, обычно используют MVC или MVVM. Код делится на модель (часть, общающаяся с базой), представление (интерфейс, формы, таблицы, окна) и контроллер/VM (то, что отвечает за логику).

Так вот, модельный класс — это класс, относящийся к модели.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static class CommonObjects
{
    public static MyType Gadget;
    public static CommonObjects()
    {
        Gadget = new MyType();
    }
}
```

Это должно быть вне `namespace`, чтобы вы из любой точки когда могли обращаться к `CommonObjects.Gadget`